# error after changing username in vboxclient:

Tags: virtualbox, accessibility, username

I changed my username that I use in virtualbox and then I can not log into my Ubuntu. When I write my password and try to start my virtual machine, I receive the follow message: `VBoxClient: Creating Pid-File VERR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you did not add the user to the 'vboxusers' group.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried to add the user using: usermod -aG vboxuser <username> but I could not change anything.